# While creating a powershell script to stop a service, the service gets stuck and when trying to kill the session it is having issues

Tags: powershell

```
$serviceName = 'SystemSettings'
$serviceData = Get-Service -Name $serviceName
If ($serviceData.Status -eq 'Running')
{
  Stop-Service -Name $serviceName
  If($serviceData.Status -eq 'StopPending')
{
  taskkill /IM SystemSettings /F
}

}
```

When i am stopping the service the status goes to `Stoppending` and when i am trying to kill the service from the task manager it is not doing that.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Is this 'SystemSettings' some custom service you wrote or was written for you? There is no such default service in Win10 at least. I've personally never seen a native service go into a ```StopPending``` state, there is ```Stop_Pending```.

Comment: Actually it is not in Windows 10 .There is a separate server in which i am working in which i have to stop a service at a particular time in a day and then restart ,so when i am applying service stop it gets stuck the status shows as stoppending in service manager then i have to kill that from task manager ,that is creating an issue

Comment: It is not getting killed

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
Clear-Host
    
$serviceName = 'SystemSettings'
$serviceData = Get-Service -Name $serviceName -ErrorAction Stop

If ($serviceData.Status -eq 'Running') 
{ 
    Stop-Service -Name $serviceName -Force
    Write-Host "The target service $serviceName was successfully stopped." -ForegroundColor Green
}
Else
{
    Write-Warning -Message "There is an issue with stopping $serviceData"
    $Error[0].Exception
}
```

... or this way.

```
Clear-Host

Try
{
    $serviceName = 'SystemSettings'
    $serviceData = Get-Service -Name $serviceName -ErrorAction Stop

    If ($serviceData.Status -eq 'Running') 
    { 
        Stop-Service -Name $serviceName -Force -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "The target service $serviceName was successfully stopped." -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
Catch
{
    Write-Warning -Message "There is an issue with stopping $serviceData"
    $Error[0].Exception
}
Finally 
{
    # Run a stop command as administrator
    Start-Process -FilePath 'powershell' -Credential $(Get-Credential) -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Stop-Process -Name $serviceName -Force -verb runas}'

}
```

Comment: Still not stopping same it is going into stoppending

Comment: Are there dependencies with the target service? If there are that they must first be stopped as well. Just like you cannot delete a folder until all files are removed.

Comment: no there are no dependencies on it . No code is executing after stopping the service .It does not allow to go to next line .When i am doing through the terminal it is killing the session but not letting the code

Comment: 1.$ serviceName='SampleManagerDynAgent_SCP'   2.$serviceData= Get-Service -Name $serviceName  3.while ($serviceData.Status -eq 'Running') {Stop-Service $serviceData.Status   Start-Sleep seconds 10        $serviceData.Refresh()     $serviceData = Get-Service -Name $serviceName    If($serviceData.Status -eq 'StopPending') {$ze=Get-Process Thermo.IM.DynamicAgent.WindowsService    $ze.kill() } }

Comment: We have to stop a service and start a particular service at a particular time but while stopping it gets stuck and it state becomes StopPending but when i try to kill it through the above code it's not happening when i debug it does not even go to next line it gets stuck .

Comment: Can the service be stopped using `services.msc` to begin with?